# nest.js and typeorm entities - exclude nested property using groups

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

I am having two entities, user and profile. I am trying to hide some properties from Profile class using @Expose with groups.

While expose and grouping works as expected on user.entity it seems it's not propagate on the profile model.

Models

```
export const GROUP_ME = 'group_user_me';

export class User extends BaseEntity { 
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  @Expose({ groups: [GROUP_ME] })
  id: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Profile, (profile) => profile.user)
  @JoinColumn()
  @Expose({ groups: [GROUP_ME] })
  @Type(() => Profile)
  profile: Profile;
}
```

and profile entity

```
export class Profile {

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  @Expose({ groups: [GROUP_ME] })
  name: string;
}
```

User.controller

```
export class UsersController {

  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  @Get('user')
  @SerializeOptions({
    groups: [GROUP_ME],
  })
.....
```

Response of get /user

```
{
    "id": "XXXXX",
    "profile": {},
}
```

If I remove the @expose from Profile, it works as expected. Any idea?

Logging the response of the repository

```
User {
  id: '48ca89ed-6b5e-4f38-8b24-a60a4cccf860',
  phone: '+XXXXXX',
  location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 51.5, -0.11 ] },
  geohash: 'gcpuvrrch',
  profile: Profile {
    id: 'b229adbf-4218-4a4e-b050-b0e1d204423f',
    name: 'string',
    username: 'X',
    gender: 'boy',
    isActive: true,
    photoKey: 'string',
    bio: null,
    email: 't@gmail.com',
    birthday: '2021-01-12',
    city: City {
      id: '728d6976-1ec8-11ec-be47-accd019b0959',
      name: 'London',
      countryName: 'United Kingdom',
      countryCode: 'GB'
    }
  }
}
```

while the actual response or the manual plainToClass(User, test,{groups: [GROUP_ME]})

returns:

```
{
    "id": "48ca89ed-6b5e-4f38-8b24-a60a4cccf860",
    "phone": "+XXXX",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            51.5,
            -0.11
        ]
    },
    "geohash": "gcpuvrrch",
    "profile": {}
}
```

Comment: it looks like it should be working... i have also made a small code to imitate this and it worked as expected. are you sure the entity itself in-fact has `Profile.name` attribute? can you post your response or some code to reproduce?

Comment: Hi @HagaiKalinhoff thanks for your response. It's really odd. I tried a simple example too and it's working as expected. I will try tonight to share here somehow the actual code to reproduce it.

Comment: still not luck - I updated my question @HagaiKalinhoff

Comment: weird, please try to remove the `@SerializeOptions({ groups: [GROUP_ME] })` and make use of the `@UseInterceptor(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(new Reflector(), { groups: [GROUP_ME] }))`. reflector is from the `@nestjs/core` package

Comment: just tried that too. Same result :(